# Pi2 GPIO only outputting 4.7v

Tags: output, gpio

I have written code that turns 8 relays on and off in a "tune" pattern. The code is working as it should do. Only one relay is open at a time, however sometimes one or two of the relays wont shut again when told (even thought the indication LED for these channels goes out saying it has been shut) and the program will just carry on leaving it open . This isn't a problem at the moment as i have nothing attached to the relays but as soon as i do i am worried that it will cause damage if a couple of the relays get stuck open.

The question i have is... are the relays getting stuck open because the Pi is only supplying 4.7v to the relays rather than the 5v it is supposed to. I am using the original PSU that came with the Pi so am hoping that isnt the problem.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stackoverflow.com! Please make your question a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Also check [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your post answerable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it belongs on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/